# What AQ$_PLSQL_NTFNnnnn scheduler jobs are used for?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I don't use Advanced Queueing at all, but amount of `AQ$_PLSQL_NTFNnnnn` scheduler jobs grows continuously.

Currently there are 8 such jobs. And because of them - I need to refresh maximum simultaneous jobs running count.

About 2 months ago it was ok with limit of 10, currently I have limit 15 and because of 8 "unnecessary" (at least for me) that jobs - I need to increase it to even 20 or 25 :-S

So, what are they used for? Can I just drop/disable them?

**UPD**: I've increased number of simultaneous jobs to 25 and in this night the amount of AQ... jobs rose up to 25 :-S Is it a joke?!

Comment: Did you try dropping them? Anything bad happen?

Comment: @alex: well, I dropped several just to have free slots to run **my** jobs. Haven't experienced any issues yet, but I bet that something could happen (just because everything has reason, even automatic creation of system jobs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like something is using AQ somewhere in your database.

I googled around a bit, and there is some possibly useful information here - http://www.ora600.be/node/5547 - mostly the hidden parameter _srvntfn_max_concurrent_jobs that apparently limits the total number of jobs running for notifications.

Information seems to be hard to come by, but apparently notifications go into the table sys.alert_qt, so you could try having a look in there to see what appears.

You could also have a look in the ALL_QUEUES and other ALL_QUEUE* tables to see if there are any queues on your database you are not aware of.

I am assuming you are using Oracle 11gR1 or 11gR2?

Comment: Nothing on the whole server uses AQ. At least nothing custom. Will see  `ALL_QUEUES` table, but if it is something there - it is definitely native oracle's stuff.

Comment: Are there any rows in SYS.ALERT_QT?  If so, any indication from the data what is creating them?

Also, how many rows does 'select owner, name from all_queues' return? My database has about 40 owned by IX, sys, sysman, wmsys and system - no other queues have ever been created on this instance.

Comment: there are 37 rows in `all_queues` owned by `sysman`, `wmsys`, `system` and `sys`. And nothing in `sys.alert_qt` :-S

Comment: Even though I did not get an answer - I present you a bounty for your attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When using a PL/SQL Callback function for processing the AQ queue, we have seen these jobs being generated.  You can check this table to find any registered subscriptions:

```
  select * from   dba_subscr_registrations;
```

[More about AQ PL/SQL Callback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a89852/dbms_a16.htm)